# Is there an intrinsic function to zero out the last n bytes of a __m128i vector?

Tags: c, vectorization, sse, simd

Given `n`, I want to zero out the last `n` bytes of a `__m128i` vector.

For instance consider the following `__m128i` vector:

`11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`

After zeroing out the last `n = 4` bytes, the vector should look like:

`11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`

Is there a SSE intrinsic function that does this (by accepting a `__128i` vector and `n` as parameters)?

Comment: I assume, `n` is not known at compile time? What SSE version are you targeting?

Comment: Clearing can be done with a pair of shifts; can you use _two_ intrinsic functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various options that don't rely on AVX512. For example:

## unaligned load

```
char mask[32] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

__m128i zeroLowestNBytes(__m128i x, uint32_t n)
{
    __m128i m = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mask[16 - n]);
    return _mm_and_si128(x, m);
}
```

With AVX, the load can become a memory operand of the `vpand`. Without AVX it's still fine, with `movdqu` and `pand`.

The load being unaligned isn't normally a problem, unless it crosses a 4K boundary. If you can get `mask` 32-aligned then that problem would go away. The load would still be unaligned, but wouldn't hit that particular edge case.

`n` is an `uint32_t` to avoid sign-extension.

## broadcast & compare

```
__m128i zeroLowestNBytes(__m128i x, int n)
{
    __m128i threshold = _mm_set1_epi8(n);
    __m128i index = _mm_set_epi8(15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0);
    return _mm_andnot_si128(_mm_cmpgt_epi8(threshold, index), x);
}
```

This avoids the unaligned load, but that shouldn't really matter. More importantly, it avoids the "input-dependent load": in the version with the unaligned load, the load depends on `n`. In this version, the load is independent of `n`. For example, that allows a compiler to hoist it out of a loop, if this function is inlined. It also allows out-of-order execution more freedom to start the load early, perhaps before `n` has been computed.

The flipside is, it basically requires AVX2 or SSSE3 for a decent realization of `_mm_set1_epi8(n)`. Also, this normally costs more instructions, which may be worse for throughput. The latency should be better, since there is no load in the "main chain" (there is a load, but it's off to the side, it doesn't add its latency to the latency of the computation).

Comment: `alignas(32) char mask[] = {...}` is ISO C11 (with `#include <stdalign.h>` and also standard ISO C++11.

Comment: `_mm_set1_epi8` is not bad with just SSSE3 for `pshufb` with an all-0 vector.  It just costs 1 extra `pxor`-zeroing instruction vs. `vpbroadcastb`.  If the critical path is through the `__m128i x`, not `int n`, then either way is good.

Comment: If the critical path is through `n`, there's not a huge difference in latency.  If runtime variable `n` starts in an integer register, a load can use `n` in an addressing mode directly.  128-bit vector load-use is about 5 or 6 cycles avoiding cache-line splits on SnB-family if hot in L1d.  So load + PAND latency ~= 6 or 7 cycles from `n` ready to retval ready.  The ALU way costs `movd` (1c Intel, 3 on Zen, much worse on Bulldozer) + shuffle (1c) + pcmpgt (1c) + pandn (1c) = 4c on Intel best case, 6 on Zen.  Bulldozer is mostly irrelevant, but has 2c SIMD ALU latency and much slower MOVD.

Comment: So almost always, saving front-end uops with an unaligned load is good.  The broadcast way still needs a data load that can cache miss.  (Unless this is in a loop and that's hoisted)

Comment: @harold For better performance with zeroing out using unaligned load technique that you mentioned, should i create `mask` like `__attribute__ ((aligned(32))) char mask[] = {...}` ?

Comment: @RonakSharma better to write `alignas(32) const char mask[] = ...` Machine code is the same, but the attributes are specific to gcc/clang, while `alignas` is in the language standard (will work for all modern compilers).

Comment: @RonakSharma Can you confirm the `mask` is a global variable?

Comment: @RonakSharma If it’s a local non-static variable, compiler will emit code to align it on the stack. If it’s a local static variable, compiler will emit code to synchronize threads. Global variables are the only ones without runtime overhead, thery’re allocated, and aligned, by linker.

Comment: @Soonts Yes `mask` is global. My mistake. I just checked. It was `const` that was causing the performance hit. Idk why. Removing `const` fixed it. Also, am I better off not using `alignas` at all? Will compiler do a decent job at aligning my `char` array?

Comment: @RonakSharma Compilers don’t align byte arrays unless asked to. When unaligned, it’s possible it will cross cache line boundary, that will cost performance. Also it’s strange `const` decreases performance, never saw anything like that.

Comment: @Soonts Yeah i know. It's sounds impossible that `const` can affect runtime performance. But it does in my code when i use `const` for a global array. Assembly code generated with and without `const` in global scope is different.

Comment: @PeterCordes can you please tell why using `const` for my global `char` array is slowing down the execution of my code by 30%?

Comment: @RonakSharma Have you replaced `(__m128i*)&mask[16 - n]` with `(const __m128i*)&mask[16 - n]` ?

Comment: @Soonts Thanks for the comment! I tried replacing `(__m128i*)&mask[16 - n]` with `(const __m128i*)&mask[16 - n]` but that didn't fix it

Comment: @Soonts: local static variables *with constant initializers* are just as cheap as regular globals.  It's just a different scope for compile-time name resolution.  Compilers only invent a guard variable if a static local needs runtime initialization.

Comment: @RonakSharma: I can't tell you what's going on in your specific case without any details or a [mcve] test case.  There's no reason to expect that in the general case.  If I had to guess, I'd guess you forgot `alignas(32)` and the `const` version (in `.rodata`) happened to cross a cache line boundary but it didnt with it in `.data`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I posted a question for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636012/using-const-in-a-particular-situation-causes-a-performance-hit

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve the desired result by "broadcasting" zero to the desired bytes at the end of your vector using `_mm_mask_set1_epi8` intrinsic:

```
__m128i _mm_mask_set1_epi8 (__m128i src, __mmask16 k, char a)
```

- `src` is your `__m128i` vector
- `__mmask16` is constructed from `n` as `(1 << n) - 1`, i.e. a mask with `n` ones at the end
- `char a` is zero

Comment: `_mm_mask_set1_epi8` requires AVX512, though (not sure if OP has that).