# Using `const` on a vector lookup table (indexed by another constant) causes a performance hit

Tags: c++, performance, x86, clang, microbenchmark

Using `const` on the `mask[]` array in this particular code causes a performance hit. (From [Is there an intrinsic function to zero out the last n bytes of a __m128i vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582402/is-there-an-intrinsic-function-to-zero-out-the-last-n-bytes-of-a-m128i-vector/63585821#63585821))

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdint.h>

alignas(32) const char mask[] = {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                                 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                                 -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

inline __m128i zeroLowestNBytes(__m128i x, uint32_t n) {
  __m128i m = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mask[16 - n]);
  return _mm_and_si128(x, m);
}

// Uses mask array
static void probe_sse(benchmark::State& state) {
  uint16_t hash[16] = {3,   4,  100, 52, 22,  12, 53, 100,
                       100, 32, 45,  67, 100, 52, 23, 66};

  uint8_t ele = 100;
  __m128i _hash = _mm_set_epi8(3, 4, 100, 52, 22, 12, 53, 100, 100, 32, 45, 67,
                               100, 52, 23, 66);
  __m128i _ele = _mm_set1_epi8(ele);
  volatile uint16_t tmp;
  uint16_t match;
  int i;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    match = _mm_movemask_epi8(zeroLowestNBytes(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(_ele, _hash), 6));
    tmp = match;

    while (tmp) {
      i = _tzcnt_u32(tmp);
      tmp = _blsr_u32(tmp);
    }
  }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Doesn't use mask array
static void probe_bitwise_and(benchmark::State& state) {
  uint16_t hash[16] = {3,   4,  100, 52, 22,  12, 53, 100,
                       100, 32, 45,  67, 100, 52, 23, 66};

  uint8_t ele = 100;
  __m128i _hash = _mm_set_epi8(3, 4, 100, 52, 22, 12, 53, 100, 100, 32, 45, 67,
                               100, 52, 23, 66);
  __m128i _ele = _mm_set1_epi8(ele);
  volatile uint16_t tmp;
  uint16_t match;
  int i;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    match = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(_ele, _hash));
    tmp = match & 0b1111111111000000;

    while (tmp) {
      i = _tzcnt_u32(tmp);
      tmp = _blsr_u32(tmp);
    }
  }
}

// ------------------ Run the benchmark -----------------------
BENCHMARK(probe_sse);
BENCHMARK(probe_bitwise_and);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

I run the code using:

```
clang++ bm.cc -std=c++11 -isystem benchmark/include -Lbenchmark/build/src -lbenchmark -lpthread -o bm -march=native -O3 && ./bm
```

The benchmark results are for the above mentioned code, on a i5-5250U Intel Broadwell CPU (2015 Macbook Air 13"):

```
Run on (4 X 1600 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x2)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x2)
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x2)
  L3 Unified 3072 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 1.41, 1.74, 2.23
***WARNING*** Library was built as DEBUG. Timings may be affected.
------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                  Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------
probe_sse               4.71 ns         4.67 ns    147819348
probe_bitwise_and       4.83 ns         4.80 ns    148097059
```

However, removing `probe_bitwise_and` function fixes the issue. Benchmark after removing `probe_bitwise_and` function from my code:

```
Run on (4 X 1600 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x2)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x2)
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x2)
  L3 Unified 3072 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 1.94, 1.80, 2.05
***WARNING*** Library was built as DEBUG. Timings may be affected.
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark           Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
probe_sse        3.75 ns         3.67 ns    202104777
```

I ran the benchmarks repeatedly and the results are consistent. `const` shouldn't affect runtime performance but it does in this particular case. Can someone please explain why is this happening?

(Editor's note: it appears the code under test was compiled with `clang++ -O3 -march=native`, but the benchmark library itself was an un-optimized(?) debug build.)

Comment: Why are you timing DEBUG builds?

Comment: Try compiling both ways to assembler, then running diff on the two outputs.  Is there any extra code, or is it just the section difference for mask?  Try the same with nm on the executables -- is there a substantial difference, or just that one symbol.  Also, this `(__m128i*)&mask[16 - n]` -- shouldn't you propagate the const? Is C++ permitted to do something stupid if you drop the const or violate the alignment?  ok, silly question.

Comment: @MartinYork The build command OP posted in the question contains "-march=native -O3" - that's not a debug build, that's an optimized build.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I guess it was `lbenchmark` that was build as debug, and that may affect timings (as the warning suggests)

Comment: What `const` are you talking about adding/removing here?

Comment: Instead of `volatile` you should use `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(tmp);`

Comment: @DavisHerring I never said anything about adding/removing `const`

Comment: @RonakSharma: Then how have you determined that `const` is responsible for a performance hit?

Comment: @RonakSharma then what do you mean in your question Title?

Comment: @rustyx I said that using `const char mask[]` in global scope causes a slight performance hit when there are atleast 2 functions in my code. Remove `probe_bitwise_and` function fixes this. I guess it's a compiler issue and I think I should just move on

Comment: Try adding `static`:  `static const char mask[]`.  Compare the differences in the assembly language listing.  I have found in some compilers that adding `static` allows the compiler to access the data directly from the read-only segment, rather than making a copy.

Comment: Your `uint32_t n` is a compile-time constant `6`, so `const` probably makes the difference in the compiler being able to see the mask at compile time and do the zeroing in a way of its choice, or at least hoist the constant vector mask out of the loop.  That should normally help, barring compiler missed optimizations.  But maybe you hit something like the JCC erratum workaround penalty on Intel Skylake-family CPUs?  What hardware are you testing on exactly?

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the comment! I'm testing my code on a (2015) macbook air 13" model. Detailed info about the cpu: https://controlc.com/7ebc9618

Comment: Your benchmark is pointless; the compile-time constant propagation eliminates all the vector work, resulting in just an integer loop that starts with `mov  word ptr [rsp + 14], 8576` to store a value into `volatile unsigned short tmp`.  https://godbolt.org/z/avExos.  Any performance variation is just code-alignment quirks.  Also, this is why `volatile` is a bad approach; it adds a store/reload store-forwarding bottleneck into the loop.  Removing `const` does make it do some vector work before the outer loop, but the `match=...` vector work is still hoisted out of the repeat loop.